# Xcode 4 - Workspaces

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios5, workspace

I'm using Xcode 4 workspace and have a framework project and base project, what is the best method to access classes form the framework project inside the base project without copying the files to the base project or rebuilding the app each with each Run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the best, but what has worked for me is to add the framework (built by the framework project) to the list of frameworks linked to the application in the base project. To do this, you can select the base project in the project navigator and select the Build Phases tab. Under there expand the "Link Binary with Libraries" section. Click on the plus button to add a library, and it should show you linkable libraries or frameworks available within the current workspace. Select the framework built by your framework project, and it will be linked into your base project's binary.